# igraph plotting with cairo error

Tags: python, igraph, pycairo

I am trying to create a plot with python igraph:

```
from igraph import *

vertices = ["one", "two", "three"]
edges = [(0,2),(2,1),(0,1)]

g = Graph(vertex_attrs={"label": vertices}, edges=edges, directed=True)

plot(g)
```

I have installed all of these:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
sudo pip install cffi
sudo pip install cairocffi
```

And I still get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/chovanec/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/igraph/drawing/__init__.py", line 446, in plot
    result = Plot(target, bbox, background=kwds.get("background", "white"))
  File "/home/chovanec/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/igraph/drawing/__init__.py", line 117, in __init__
    self._surface_was_created = not isinstance(target, cairo.Surface)
AttributeError: module 'cairo' has no attribute 'Surface'
```

I can't find what's causing it.

Comment: You might have another module named `cairo` in your Python path that "shadows" the "real" `cairo` module. Type `import cairo; print cairo.__file__` to figure out where it is coming from.

Comment: You're right it was pointing to the wrong this. I additionally had to install a newer version of igraph: https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues/88

Comment: Why on my os __file__ returns `no attribute` error